# How do I get rid of monitor audio devices from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, multiple-monitors, speakers

I have 5 Dell monitors connected to my Windows 10 pc, and they have build-in speakers it seems - at least they show up as "Audio inputs and Outputs" in Device manager - and in the "Select Playback Device" popup from the Sound icon in the tray.

Since I switch between speakers (not the monitor speakers) and headset many times a day, it is annoying me, that I cannot get rid of the monitors from that list.

[image]

As you can see from above screenshot from Device Manager, I have disabled them.

[image]

...but they still show up here in the tray sound menu as available devices.

**How do I get rid of these audio devices - or at least get them out of my sound tray menu?**

What I have tried:

- Disabling and rebooting (they are still in the tray list)
- Uninstalling the drivers for the monitor speakers (they re-appear when they are later detected again)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Open the Sound Settings, click "Sound Control Panel" and disable the devices you want to get rid of from there.

[image: Sound Countrol Panel link]

[image: disabling a device]

Comment: Finally a useful answer. Been struggling with two new monitors that has HDMI audio capabilites. Tried to disable them by deleting devices from Device manager, reinstalled on reboot. Tried uninstalling Nvidia audio drivers and delete them, reinstalled upon reboot.. grrrrr! now THIS trick... this seems awesome and logical. What I don't get from Windows 10 and Microsoft... WHY THE F**K do I have to know 3-5 ways of handling the very same topic in one Operating System. That's really stupid.

Answer (score 6):

As of the latest Windows 10 updates, this is now possible with mostly native Windows 10 controls.

Settings, System, Sound, Manage Sound Devices

[image: Windows 10 sound settings]

Locate the devices that you don't want to provide sound, select them, and press the Disable button on each one.

[image: manage sound devices, disable]