# Monitor playback device - Windows switches between playback devices when monitor is switched on

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi, playback

I have headphones (Razer Kraken X with virtual 7.1 surround sound) plugged in to my desktop, I also have a monitor (MSI Optix) connected via HDMI. I have regular stereo speakers plugged into my monitor.

The issue is that when the monitor wakes up or is turned on, Windows switches between the playback devices for about 5 mins before settling on one - usually the headphones.

I have a video of this happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0auo.jpg

Audio will play through my headphones while it's doing this, but it's got static on it. Once it settles, everything is fine.

Until I can figure out what the issue is, I've disabled the monitor device as per the answer here: [How do I get rid of monitor audio devices from Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1478390/how-do-i-get-rid-of-monitor-audio-devices-from-windows-10). But I do use my speakers, so would like to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Why wouldn't you plug the speakers directly into the PC and keep the monitor audio disabled?  This doesn't make sense to me.  If it's just for the convenience of having the plug on the monitor.. hrrmmm..

Comment: See [this guy's](https://superuser.com/questions/996095/how-to-set-audio-device-priority) answer.  It might help.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I need to plug my headphones into the desktop so I can use the attached mic (no mic input on monitor or speakers). Occasionally I use the speakers for playing music and I don't want to always reach behind the desktop to switch cables. The set up "works", it's just the rapid-switching that is throwing it off.